# custom excel data validation formula restrict input to time, blank, or "-"

Tags: validation, time, excel-formula

I am trying to write a data validation rule using excels data validation custom option (for a spreadsheet that records and processes service times (Time of day) so that input is restricted to time but the user can also distinguish which entries have still to be input and which have no data from the source.  I therefore need to say that each cell in the given range (a column) must be either a valid time entry in format "hh:mm", or blank, or "-" (to indicate that there is no service.  The column in question has format hh:mm.
So far i have the following, which does not work.

=OR(TIMEVALUE(TEXT(Q1248,"hh,mm,ss")),"","-")

I get warning "The formula currently evaluates to an error"
and then it will reject all input.

Many thanks in advance to anyone who can help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ask "is this cell equal to this value?  True or False?"

Blanks are ignored by ticking the "Ignore blank" check box on the *Data Validation* dialog.

`=Q1248=TIMEVALUE(TEXT(Q1248,"hh:mm:ss"))` will answer the question of *Is Q1248 equal to Q1248 when it's forced to a time value?*

The problem occurs when it tries to calculate the value `-` as text formatted as time. It returns a #VALUE error.
If it could your formula would be `=OR(Q1248=TIMEVALUE(TEXT(Q1248,"hh:mm:ss")),Q1248="-")` - *does Q1248 equal the time value, or does Q1248 equal a dash?*  but it will try and evaluate both parts of the `OR` statement and the first part returns an error so the whole formula returns an error.

This appears to work as data validation (with no custom number formatting):
`=IF(ISNUMBER(Q1250),Q1250=TIMEVALUE(TEXT(Q1250,"hh:mm:ss")),Q1250="-")`

If the value isn't a number then the second part of the `IF` is evaluated, otherwise the first part is and no error occurs.

---

*As pointed out this won't work as the data validation will try and convert "-" to a time value which will cause an error:*

`=Q1248=TIMEVALUE(TEXT(Q1248,"hh:mm:ss"))` and giving the cell a **custom number format** of `hh:mm;"-";"-"`.
Any positive number will be shown as a time, a 0 or negative number will show as `-`.
Just use `0` rather than `-` to get the result you're after.

Comment: thanks, this does work.  However, it returns "-" if "00:00" is entered.  (I will clarify the question. Hours are time of day rather than duration)

Comment: Change the custom number format to `hh:mm;"-";hh:mm`.  Positive numbers and 0 will be formatted as time, negative numbers formatted as `-`.  Use -1 instead of 0, but be mindful of the -1's if you're performing calculations on the column.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.  That doesn't work, -1 returns error.

Comment: Good point, -1 can't be translated into a date so it's failing on the data validation.

Comment: yup, brilliant!   Thankyou!  That seems to work perfectly.

Comment: Good stuff.  Feel free to tick as accepted after you've tested. :)